# Calling the github:davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer using JavaScript without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm trying to use the https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer iframe resizer and the example (https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/tree/master/example) seems to be based on JQuery.  Does anyone know how to call this via JavaScript only without using JQuery?  Does it need a body onload or do I capture the onload event of the iframe? I'm confused on how to start using it (Invoke it).

**Edit...to add more details per questions.**

1. Why? Dynamic content:
   I need my iframe to dynamically adjust its height based on the "changing" content within the iframe.  I've tried a number of solutions like the one below but they do not "*entirely*" solve the problem 100% of the time.  They set the size only based on the "first page" of the iframe content:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   //Credit for script: http://th.atguy.com/mycode/100_percent_iframe/
   <script language="JavaScript">

   function resize_iframe()
   {

   var height=window.innerWidth;//Firefox
   if (document.body.clientHeight)
   {
       height=document.body.clientHeight;//IE
   }
   //resize the iframe according to the size of the
   //window (all these should be on the same line)
   document.getElementById("glu").style.height=parseInt(height-
   document.getElementById("glu").offsetTop-8)+"px";
   }

   // this will resize the iframe every
   // time you change the size of the window.
   window.onresize=resize_iframe; 

   //Instead of using this you can use: 
   //  <BODY onresize="resize_iframe()">
   //--></script>
   ```
2. Existing Docs./Not figuring it out: 
   I'm not following the existing documentation provided by DavidBradshaw on how to do this:  I tried adding this code as follows.   But apparently, that is NOT how you do it.

The body of the file is:

```
    <iframe src="http://www.domain.net/store20/StoreTop.aspx?StoreID=17" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="iFrameResize()"></iframe>
```

The script portion:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/iframeResizer.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    <script language="JavaScript">
    iFrameResize(); 
    // this will resize the iframe every
    // time you change the size of the window.
    window.onresize=iFrameResize; 
    //Instead of using this you can use: 
    //  <BODY onresize="resize_iframe()">
    //--></script>
```

Also at the called content within the iframe, I have this line of code.  I'm pretty sure this part is correct, though.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.  I apologize if I seem dense or its a stupid question but I see the example prototyped:  iFrameResize([{options}],[selector]);

However, don't you need an "event" to trigger that function?  See my code and I use the onload event and it doesn't work.  If I set the ID of the iframe to establish a [selector]:

```
    <iframe id="testframe" src="http://www.domain.net/store20/StoreTop.aspx?StoreID=17" width="100%" scrolling="no" onload="iFrameResize()"></iframe>
```

and call it like:

```
    iFrameResize(,testframe);
```

or this:

```
    iFrameResize(,$("#testframe"));
```

It still doesn't work.  I don't have any options and want to keep the options as default.

Comment: And what's your reason for doing this? (Besides making life harder?)

Comment: The example uses jQuery to do DOM operations. You don't need it.

Comment: The documentation also shows how to use it without jquery.'

Comment: Thanks guys...I edited my question to add details.

Comment: Code blocks inside lists should be indented with 8 spaces, btw.

Comment: Fabricio: I'm using ctrl-K and I can't make it work....I've been trying for 20mins now.  OK Got it.

Comment: Yep, crtl+K does not work properly inside of lists. It might be worth posting a bug report in [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Straight from the Github page you linked to: _"It can be called with native JavaScript: `iFrameResize([{options}],[selector]);`"_...

Comment: Yeh, I see that in the documentation and its not obvious to me what he is talking about without a "direct example.  I don't have any options and am trying to use the defaults.  My code is calling iFrameResize([no options],called directly from onload as ME);  I can also give the iframe an id=testframe [selector] and call it like it seems to infer.  iFrameResize(,testframe);  That's my problem.  I'm not seeing how to translate the "prototype" to reality.  He gives a prototype without giving a prototype in practice.  JQuery is prototyped and exampled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do either.

```
$("#testframe").iFrameResize();
```

or

```
iFrameResize(null,"#testframe");
```

Comment: From the number of times this page has been viewed, and how long i've spent trying to resolve similar confusion, i think it would be helpful if you put instructions for noobs on your page. We're out there, and we want to use your very helpful JS package, but you've explained it for people who know more than we do. I found this answer after searching for hours, and only after finally starting to draft a question here on SO. I barely use JS but i need it for this one particular thing - i don't know the conventions for how parameters are written, or scripts like this are called within a page.

Comment: @kimholder Did you see the Typical Example straight after the Getting Started section? I have just updated this to include setting an ID on the iFrame and passing this to iFrameResize().

Comment: Yes, i saw that. The addition is an improvement. But - calling the script, with `var iframes = iFrameResize( [{options}], [css selector] || [iframe] );` - Where does this go and how should it be wrapped? What goes within the last option after the double vbar? What part of the syntax is just a convention for saying 'substitute here', the square brackets? I wish a page elsewhere explained that kind of thing for those just wanting to use plugins, for everyone to link to for noobs. Also <style> should go in the head, putting style="width: 100%;" in the opening iframe tag is normal syntax - right?

Comment: [] means optional, || means 'or'. These are very common conventions.  The 'iframe' bit means you can pass an object reference of an iFrame, if that doesn't make sense then you don't need it. I think 90%!of people only ever need the typical example, maybe that should come first. Yes the style bit should really be in the head, but trying to keep things small. I would really expect that to be placed in a CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
iFrameResize(,'iframe#testframe');
```